How Can I Write 'Stream:$DATA' in PowerShell and Delete ':$DATA' in Batch?

Attempted to remove :$DATA Stream from a file in cmd and nothing works, except powershell, it is no longer possible to remove using pure cmd/batch?
Recreating/reproducing the scenario and showing the failed attempts...

1st write strings to the :Stream in the file:

>"C:\Path\To\LogError.Log::Stream.Report" (echo/[CopyStatus]&echo/Error=3)



2nd read the strings from the :Stream in the file:

more < "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" 
:: output:
[CopyStatus]
Error=3



3rd list/check the :Stream in the file:

dir /r "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" | find "$DATA"
:: Output:
25 LogError.Log:Stream.Report:$DATA



4th attempts to remove :Stream.Report (:$DATA) from the file by multiple tries:

cd.>"C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report"
cd.>"\\?\C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:StreamReport'"

echo.>"C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" 
echo.>"\\?\C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report"

more < nul > "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" 
more < nul > "\\?\C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" 

fsutil reparsepoint delete "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report"
fsutil reparsepoint delete "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report"

wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Path\\To\\LogError.Log'" delete "Stream.Report"
wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Path\\To\\LogError.Log:Stream.Report'" delete "Stream.Report"



5th list/check (again) the :Stream in the file to verify if they have been removed:

dir /r "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" | find "$DATA"
:: output 
25 LogError.Log:Stream.Report:$DATA

more < "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" 
:: Output:
[CopyStatus]
Error=3


Nothing changes... $DATA remains in the file.


What I'm trying to do and I'm stuck.
I successfully removed the contents of the :Stream: but did not exclude the $DATA stream from the file; it is still present:
>dir /r LogError.Log
 Directory of C:\Path\To

10/22/2024  05:24 AM            17,083 LogError.Log
                                    25 LogError.Log:Stream.Report:$DATA
               1 File(s)         17,083 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  128,989,868,032 bytes free

There is no difficulty and it works directly with powershell
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" 
Get-Content -Path "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" 


Is there any way to remove :$DATA using pure powershell and batch? I'm looking for a solution that allows me to handle this in both environments, but I find myself facing limitations with each tool. How can I achieve the same functionality across both platform?
cmd.exe /c '(echo/[CopyStatus]&echo/Error=3)>"C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report"'

:: Not work:
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report", "[CopyStatus]")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report", "[Error=3]"   )

"[CopyStatus]" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" -Encoding utf8
   "[Error=3]" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Path\To\LogError.Log:Stream.Report" -Encoding utf8


But in cmd, I can't delete, and in powershell, I can't write. It feels like I'm stuck in between: PowerShell can perform two actions (read and delete), while cmd can also do two actions (write and read).
Why can't I have all three actions in powershell and all three actions in cmd? Is there a way to achieve that?"


In summary, the key points in the question are as follows:




Question:
To:




1. Remove: File.Log:$DATA
cmd/bat


2.     Write: File.Log:Stream:$DATA
powershell




you can make use of powershell from within a batch script to remove a specific stream.
@echo off & Cls
( More < "%~f0:streamname" ) 2> nul || (
  Set "user" >"%~f0:streamname" && Echo stream has been created:
  For /f "tokens=1,*" %%G in ('dir /r "%~f0" ^| find /i "streamname"')Do echo %%H
  Echo(contains:
  ( More < "%~f0:streamname" )
)

Set "powershell="
For /f "delims=" %%G in ('%systemroot%\system32\where.exe PowerShell.exe')Do if not defined powershell Set powershell="%%~G"
%powershell% -c "remove-item -path '%~f0' -Stream 'Streamname'

( More < "%~f0:streamname" ) 2> nul || echo stream has been removed
pause

Writing to the stream is as simple as redirecting to the desired stream name.

Thank you very much, but I must confess that I’m more concerned about the incomplete part of the question, where it refers to a 100% batch command that would delete the $DATA stream from a file, without needing to call PowerShell.exe as part of the solution.

@Io-oI If you wish to exclusively use a single language, you should be able to achieve that in powershell. set-content supports arguments for path, stream name and encoding, which gives you a way to output to a stream. As for batch, it has no native command for stream removal, but any standard windows install from 7 onwards has powershell by default, so there is a tool available for batch scripts to be able to remove streams.

With your code, I now have a 100% solution in PowerShell, but I’m still looking for a way to achieve the same in batch. The question is focused on how to reach 100% functionality in both environments.

As state @lo-ol - there is no native command in batch that facilitates stream removal. If the file concerned has only the one ADS, you could copy the primary file content into a temp file
delete the original after verifying the copy, then rename the temp file to the name of the original.

There are basically two options, copy the file to location that doesn't support Alternate Data Streams and next copping the file back to it's original location or you could make a copy of the file by using the type command:
type original.txt>copy.txt
del original.txt
ren copy.txt original.txt


Thank you for responding, but this doesn't work for my needs.. The issue with this approach is that it doesn't work because it deletes the file, causing the loss of the Streams. For example, if there are three Streams, I need to delete only one, but this method causes all the Streams to be lost.
